# Force refresh on nested function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm a complete beginner in Angular(1.x) and I've been trying to stitch it into the app I'm currently developing.

It basically receives the whole user data via ajax (multiple nested arrays) and then proceeds to render them using nested ng-repeat directives. In the innermost repeat I run a function which returns data based on the current date.

```html
<div ng-repeat="i in rootArray">
  <div ng-repeat="h in i.array1">
    <div ng-repeat="j in h.array2">
      <span>{{dateBasedFunction(j.data)}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The data from the function changes over time (even though the input remains the same), and I want it to re run in order to reflect those changes without rendering the whole structure again.

Is it possible? I'm not sure if I'm following the best framework's practices, maybe there is a better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: hi, when you're using ng-repeat, angular make a dirty watch of object, and refresh view on changes. You dont need to do it. Angular 1.x make it alone

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón unfortunately that's not the case, since the data in the object itself doesn't change. what is really changing is the system time (inside the function), so there's no way for angular to figure this out... I need to run an interval check, but I have no idea which code to run on it!

Comment: you need to know when object is changed, and this changed is not done by your responsability( like ajax ,input...). Then you need to add a watcher https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: $rootscope.$apply();

Will force the angular app to rerender the data. It's bad practice though. If your data doesn't change, why do you want to rerender it?

Comment: it seems that I have a deeper problem here... maybe I should have two data sets, one fed from the server with the raw data and another for angular to render with processed data. that way it would watch the changes properly. I will leave the topic open for now, maybe someone would come with a good alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Background**

The ng-repeats aren't causing any problems here. We need to focus on the [interpolation expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation): `{{dateBasedFunction(j.data)}}`

Angular is creating a [watcher](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) to dirty-check the expression `dateBasedFunction(j.data)` on each iteration of the [digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) cycle. If the resulting value has changed since the last digest, the DOM will be updated with the new value.

The problem is, there's nothing in your code triggering an Angular digest cycle.

**Working Example**

Here we can see your situation working by triggering digest manually via user interaction:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', MyCtrl]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  
  $scope.rootArray = [{
    "array1": [{
      "array2": [{
        "data": "hello"
      }, {
        "data": "world"
      }]
    }]
  }];

  //Dummy $watch alerts whenever digest is called
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    console.log('Digest called');
  });

  $scope.dateBasedFunction = function(x) {
    var d = new Date();
    return x + ' (' + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds() + ")";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  
  <button ng-click="">ng-click calls digest()</button>
  
    <div ng-repeat="i in rootArray">
      <div ng-repeat="h in i.array1">
        <div ng-repeat="j in h.array2">
          <span>{{dateBasedFunction(j.data)}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Every time you click the button, `ng-click` triggers an Angular digest. This re-evaluates `dateBasedFunction`. Because the value has changed, the DOM gets re-drawn.

But, I'm assuming you don't want to rely on `ng-click`s to keep the DOM updated. You want your DOM to update periodically, since it changes in response to the current date/time.

**Possible Solutions**

1. Decide on a frequency that makes sense for your needs, and force a digest cycle periodically:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', MyCtrl]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  
  $scope.rootArray = [{
    "array1": [{
      "array2": [{
        "data": "hello"
      }, {
        "data": "world"
      }]
    }]
  }];

  //Dummy $watch alerts whenever digest is called
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    console.log('Digest called');
  });

  $scope.dateBasedFunction = function(x) {
    var d = new Date();
    return x + ' (' + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds() + ")";
  }
  
  //Call $scope.$apply() every second.
  setInterval(function() {
    //$scope.$apply() triggers a digest cycle
    $scope.$apply();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  
    <div ng-repeat="i in rootArray">
      <div ng-repeat="h in i.array1">
        <div ng-repeat="j in h.array2">
          <span>{{dateBasedFunction(j.data)}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

2. If you know the frequency of the updates, you may consider writing a directive which directly updates the DOM at the right times, without calling `apply()` on the whole scope. This will be more efficient, but require more development effort.

   This is exactly what [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/) does with their [`am-time-ago` directive](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/blob/master/angular-moment.js#L232). This directive has a similar goal: to update data which changes in response to the current date/time.
3. Use Angular to watch the model for any changes, but handle the date/time-based changes outside of Angular:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', MyCtrl]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.rootArray = [{
    "array1": [{
      "array2": [{
        "data": "hello"
      }, {
        "data": "world"
      }]
    }]
  }];

  //Dummy $watch alerts whenever digest is called
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    console.log('Digest called');
  });
}

function dateBasedFunction(x) {
  var d = new Date();
  return x + ' (' + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds() + ")";
}

setInterval(function() {
  $('[data-date-based-value]').each(function() {
    this.textContent = dateBasedFunction(this.dataset['dateBasedValue']);
  });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="i in rootArray">
      <div ng-repeat="h in i.array1">
        <div ng-repeat="j in h.array2">
        
          <!--Set a data-date-based-value attribute-->
          <!--Angular will keep the attribute value updated-->
          <!--But the element's text will be updated via jQuery-->
          <span ng-attr-data-date-based-value="{{j.data}}"></span>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that this solution updates the DOM directly, without running additional digest cycles.

[This article](https://www.thinkful.com/projects/understanding-the-digest-cycle-528/) does a good job of explaining the digest cycle if you're interested in learning more about Angular.